# Understanding cabal dependency messages

Tags: haskell, dependencies, dependency-management, cabal

currently when I try to install GOA I get the following message :

```
>sudo cabal install goa
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
directory-1.1.0.2 (reinstall) changes: filepath-1.3.0.0 -> 1.2.0.1
process-1.0.1.5 (new version)
goa-3.1 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
....
```

My question is whether this means that I currently have "filepath-1.3.0.0" as default, and cabal (upon a --force-reinstalls) is going to override this and make "filepath-1.2.0.1" as default? The reason I am a bit confused is that when I look in the location :

cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/filepath

I find both 1.2.0.1 & 1.3.0.0 present. Furthermore the command "cabal list filepath" indicates that both packages are installed (see "Installed versions: 1.2.0.1, 1.3.0.0" in the below) :

```
>cabal list filepath
......
* filepath
    Synopsis: Library for manipulating FilePaths in a cross platform way.
    Default available version: 1.3.0.1
    Installed versions: 1.2.0.1, 1.3.0.0
    Homepage: http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~ndm/filepath/
    License:  BSD3
```

Comment: Heed the warning. When cabal says `cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:` it means they will almost certainly be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you have `directory-1.1.0.2` installed and built with `filepath-1.3.0.0`.

The issue here is that you're installing [`goa`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/goa) which requires `filepath (≥1.1 & <1.3)`, **and** `directory (≥1.0 & <1.2)`.  You already have all the right packages installed, but `directory` was built with a too new version of `filepath`.  Cabal-install's solution to this conflict is to rebuild `directory` so that it uses the older version of `filepath`.  All of this is done because you shouldn't have multiple versions of the same package in the dependencies of a package (`goa` in this case).

Comment: Thanks that was nicely explained.