# Using cabal-dev to avoid dependency conflicts

Tags: haskell, dependencies, dependency-management, cabal

Currently I have cabal installed globally as specified in [Installing cabal globally by Volker Schatz](http://www.volkerschatz.com/haskell/glocabal.html). In the post [Understanding cabal dependency messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726483/understanding-cabal-dependency-messages) I was getting dependency conflicts when trying to install GOA, and would therefore like to try to install GOA via cabal-dev ([cabal-dev by Rogan Creswick](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev)) in order to isolate the installation (if I understand it correctly cabal will include a sandboxing feature in the future, see [cabal sandbox by Johan Tibell](http://blog.johantibell.com/2012/08/you-can-soon-play-in-cabal-sandbox.html), but since it is still under development I would like to give cabal-dev a try).

**Question** : So given that my `~/.cabal` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/share/cabal` (as is done in url [1](http://www.volkerschatz.com/haskell/glocabal.html)), how would I go about using cabal-dev to install GOA? Ideally the installation would still be placed in `/usr/local/share/cabal`, but maybe in a specialised directory like `/usr/local/share/cabal/cabal-dev`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the purpose of cabal-dev is to create an isolated  environment just for compiling your project or a specific set of subprojects with compatible dependencies. The only thing you need to do is to run cabal-dev in the directory of your "cabalized" project, and it will locate the correct set of version for all your dependencies and compile and install them locally, in "cabal-dev" of your subdirectory. If you asked it to do that in a centralized location, like "/usr/local/...", then you would be defeating the whole purpose of cabal-dev. If you are still in doubt, please check virtualenv... cabal-dev works in a somewhat similar fashion.